# Getting rejected value null spring validation

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-form, spring-validator

Hi in my project when I am trying to validate my form its not showing any error messages even if validation fails (Even Form is not submitted and enters into validation fail block)

Here is my code

```
      /****************** Post Method *************/
       @RequestMapping(value="/property", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveOrUpdateProperty(@ModelAttribute("property") Property property, 
                BindingResult result, 
                Model model, 
                HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
                try {
                        if(validateFormData(property, result)) {
                            model.addAttribute("property", new Property());
                            return "property/postProperty";


                }
}


/********* Validate Block *************/
    private boolean validateFormData(Property property, BindingResult result) throws DaoException {
    if (property.getPropertyType() == null || property.getPropertyType().equals("")) {
        result.rejectValue("propertyType", "Cannot Be Empty !", "Cannot Be Empty !");
    } 
    if (property.getTitle() == null || property.getTitle().equals("")) {
        result.rejectValue("title", "Cannot Be Empty !", "Cannot Be Empty !");
    }
    return (result.hasFieldErrors() || result.hasErrors());
}
```

But when i debug i can see below one

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'property' on field 'title': rejected value [null]; codes [Cannot Be Empty !.property.title,Cannot Be Empty !.title,Cannot Be Empty !.java.lang.String,Cannot Be Empty !]; arguments []; default message [Cannot Be Empty !]
```

and this is how i am displaying in jsp file

```
<div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
        <label class="control-label"><span class="required">* </span>Property Type</label>
            <div class="controls">  
                <form:input path="title" placeholder="Pin Code" cssClass="form-control border-radius-4  textField"/>
                <form:errors path="title" style="color:red;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Event though when i see the below one when i debug (1 Error its correct)

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
```

Why it is not displayed in jsp can any one hep me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you cannot see anything because on the second line below you destroy your model (your validation error included) and create a new one.

```
    if(validateFormData(property, result)) {
     model.addAttribute("property", new Property());  // <------
     return "property/postProperty";
```

Try display the property that comes in as a parameter  and probably you will be able to see the validation errors.

```
    if(validateFormData(property, result)) {
     model.addAttribute("property", property);  
     return "property/postProperty";
```